# How can I set my lamp server into a static ip address of 10.10.0.23?

Tags: server

I'm using ubuntu12.04 server on virtual box and it seems it only allows me to use class c addresses as this one,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.23
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Is it possible to change it to

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 10.10.0.23
netmask 255.0.0.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.255.255.255
gateway 10.10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The IP address you use has to agree with the subnet on your router. So first you need to change your routers subnet. 10.253.0.* is more common for local networks, but you can get away with 10.10.0.* . You are also using a huge subnet mask, while you *can* use a netmask this large, there is no need to.

A better configuration would be:

```
address 10.10.0.23
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.10.0.0
broadcast 10.10.0.255
gateway 10.10.0.1
```

You will have to define a similar configuration at your router. Make sure the static IP is outside the range of your routers DHCP range.

**Edit:** Just noticed you mentioned Virtual Box. This answer still might be useful, but instead of 'router', the changes will be configured in virtual box. I'm not great with virtual box so I don't know the specifics.